# Analysis Exception in spark NLP

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

[image]
strong textBelow was my code block:

```
conll_data.select(F.explode(F.arrays_zip('token.result','label.result')).alias("cols")) \
          .select(F.expr("cols['0']").alias("token"),
                  F.expr("cols['1']").alias("ground_truth"))\
          .groupBy('ground_truth')\
          .count()\
          .orderBy('count', ascending=False)\
          .show(100,truncate=False)
```

and am getting below error:

**AnalysisException: No such struct field 0 in result, result**

and my requirements.txt is like below:

```
jupyterlab
SQLAlchemy==0.7.1
spark-nlp==3.4.4
pyspark==3.1.2
numpy== 1.19.2
pandas==1.3.2
openpyxl==3.0.9
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
spark-nlp-display
pyarrow==3.0.0
streamlit==1.1.0
scipy==1.7.3
Tensorflow==2.5.0
tensorflow-addons
python==3.7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue the other day. Zip actually uses columns that are named 1 and 2. This is an issues as these are reserved words. (Numbers) so you need to escape the column name so that SQL knows to use it as a column name that is reserved.  This is done but using ` so the columns names can be referred to as : `1` and `2`. You need to refer to them as columns not as an `array[1]`.

```
conll_data.select(F.explode(F.arrays_zip('token.result','label.result')).alias("cols")) \
          .select(F.col("cols.`0`").alias("token"),
                  F.col("cols.`1`").alias("ground_truth"))\
          .groupBy('ground_truth')\
          .count()\
          .orderBy('count', ascending=False)\
          .show(100,truncate=False)
```

#minimal example to show this works:

```
df.select(arrays_zip( array_repeat(lit(0), 10), array_repeat(lit(1), 10)).alias("cols")).select("cols.`1`").show()
+--------------------+
|                   1|
+--------------------+
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Still am getting the same error with above code/idea @Matt

Comment: I made a small change to use `col` instead of `expr` try my minimal example to see if that works for you.